# "Trying to get property of 'type' of non-object" error when sending array through Mail Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

NotiMail.php

```
public $notiInfo;

public function __construct($notiInfo)
{
    $this->type = $notiInfo->type;
    $this->name = $notiInfo->name;
}

public function build()
{
    if($this->type=="Document") {
        return $this->markdown('emails.statusDoc')->with('name', $this->name);
    }

    elseif($this->type=="Announcement") {
        return $this->markdown('emails.statusTap')->with('name', $this->name);
    }

}
```

AnnouncementController.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\NotiMail;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $hawkers = Hawker::select('hawker_id')->get();

    $request->validate([
        'announce_title' => ['required', 'unique:announcements,title'],
        'announce_desc' => ['required'],
    ]);

    $current = new Carbon('now', 'UTC');
    $Mtime = $current->addHours(8);

    $announce = new Announcement();

    $announce->title = $request->input('announce_title');
    $announce->desc = $request->input('announce_desc');
    $announce->announce_date = $Mtime;
    $announce->save();

    foreach ($hawkers as $hawk) {
        $noti = new Notification();
        $noti->hawker_id = $hawk->hawker_id;
        $noti->title = $request->input('announce_title');
        $noti->desc = $request->input('announce_desc');
        $noti->notiDate = $Mtime;
        
        $noti->save();

        $hawker = Hawker::find($hawk->hawker_id);
        $notiInfo = [
            'name' => $hawker->name,
            'type' => "Announcement"
        ];
        Mail::to($hawker->email)->send(new NotiMail($notiInfo));
    }

    return redirect()->route('announcement.index')->with('success', "Announcement made!");
}
```

The error appears from NotiMail.php. Most of the solutions where because the public variable was not included. However, as you can see i already have. Yet the array from AnnouncementController does not seem to pass the values to NotiMail.php.

Comment: you are passing an array not an object, you have to use it like an array, not an object

Comment: You are passing an array in NotiMail construction. And in NotiMail fil construction you are using object sign "->". Uset $notiInfo['type'] and $notiInfo['name'] in __construct() in notimail.php file